# springTestContextPrepareTestInstance failed in spring-test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testng

I try to setup a project with spring-test using TestNg in Maven. The code is like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebMvcTestConfig.class})
public class MyResourceParserTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() throws Exception {

}
```

A WebMvcTestConfig class simply defined a bean:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.test.myapp.model"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebMvcTestConfig {
private static final String relativeConfigURI = "\\MyAppSpringConfig\\";
private static final String userHomeURI = System.getProperty("user.home");
private static final String jdbcPropertiesFileName = "jdbc.properties";
private static final String hibernatePropertiesFileName = "hibernate.properties";

@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()         {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(userHomeURI + relativeConfigURI + jdbcPropertiesFileName));

    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(
        @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}") String driverClass,
        @Value("${jdbc.url}") String jdbcUrl,
        @Value("${jdbc.username}") String username,
        @Value("${jdbc.password}") String password) {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
    dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource("", "", "", ""));
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.test.myapp.model.domain");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        hibernateProperties.load(new FileInputStream(userHomeURI + relativeConfigURI + hibernatePropertiesFileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return hibernateProperties;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(localSessionFactoryBean().getObject());
}
```

}

I got error for Failed to load ApplicationContext when running mvn test from command line:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace. Onet hing your `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` method/definition should be static.

Comment: Thanks. I did it run successfully.

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.test.myapp.model"}) is incorrect. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

3 things I notice from your configuration.

1. Your loading of configuration files is strange, use Spring for that instead of rolling your own. Simply use `@PropertySource` for that.
2. The `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()` must be `static`
3. Your call to `datasource` will lead to an invalid datasource configuration.

Try the following configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.test.myapp.model"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"${user.home}/MyAppSpringConfig/jdbc.properties","${user.home}/MyAppSpringConfig/hibernate.properties"}
public class WebMvcTestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("env.username", ""));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("env.password", ""));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.test.myapp.model.domain");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        // Other properties
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(localSessionFactoryBean().getObject());
    }
}
```